error pulling image configuration: Get https://production.cloudflare.docker.com/....... : dial tcp 108.160.162.109:443: i/o timeout
when I run
docker pull mysql:5.5
and a lot other images, I get the error i/o timeout
error pulling image configuration: Get https://production.cloudflare.docker.com/registry-v2/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/a3/a3562aa0b991a80cfe8172847c8be6dbf6e46340b759c2b782f8b8be45342717/data?verify=1724297982-Q9XbLqXgTRafzvm5SDx4ZnN5rPA%3D: dial tcp 108.160.162.109:443: i/o timeout

How can I fix it?
I have tried registry-mirrors and proxy

Have you tried to use another Internet Service Provider? It seems you have a problem in connectivity.
